# Missing ComboBox on Grid Item Edit

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I new to telerik and fighting my way up the learning curve.

I have a RadGrid that I'm populating with a linq query. I'm using a 
GridTemplateColumn with a ComboBox for new and edit of one of the fields. The problem is the ComboBox doesn't show on the insert or edit screen. The fields set as GridDropDownColumn do show on the insert or edit. I need GridTemplateColumn solution because I need to run some code once the dropdown list has been selected.

What am I missing here? I'm trying to work from a Telerik example. It's the Release field that is giving me the problem.

```
<telerik:RadGrid RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="grdData" runat="server"
        AllowPaging="true"
        AllowSorting="true"
        AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        AllowAutomaticInserts="true" 
        AllowAutomaticUpdates="true"
        OnNeedDataSource="grdData_OnNeededDataSource" 
        OnItemDataBound="grdData_OnItemDataBound"
        OnUpdateCommand="grdData_OnUpdateCommand" >
    <ClientSettings>
        <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True" />
        <Scrolling AllowScroll="True" UseStaticHeaders="True" />
    </ClientSettings>
    <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="LightYellow" />

    <MasterTableView Width="100%" 
            DataKeyNames="TID" 
            EditMode="EditForms"
            AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
            InsertItemDisplay="Top"
            CommandItemDisplay="Top"
            InsertItemPageIndexAction="ShowItemOnFirstPage">
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn></telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="TID" UniqueName="TID" 
                HeaderText="TID" ReadOnly="true"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridDropDownColumn UniqueName="Employee" ListDataMember="Employee"
                SortExpression="Employee" ListTextField="Employee" ListValueField="Employee"
                HeaderText="Employee" DataField="Employee"
                DropDownControlType="RadComboBox"
                EnableEmptyListItem="true" EmptyListItemText="Make a choice" EmptyListItemValue=""
                />
            <telerik:GridDropDownColumn UniqueName="Job" ListDataMember="Job"
                SortExpression="Job" ListTextField="Job" ListValueField="Job"
                HeaderText="Job" DataField="Job" 
                DropDownControlType="RadComboBox"
                EnableEmptyListItem="true" EmptyListItemText="Make a choice" EmptyListItemValue=""
                />
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="Release" 
                    HeaderText="Release"
                    HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                    SortExpression="Release"
                    ItemStyle-Width="170px" HeaderStyle-Width="80px"
                    DataField="Release" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Release")%>
                </ItemTemplate>

                <telerik:EditItemTemplate>
                    <telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="rcbRelease"
                        AutoPostBack="true" 
                        EnableLoadOnDemand="true"
                        DataTextField="Release"
                        DataValueField="Release" 
                        Text='<% #Bind("Release")%>'
                        EnableEmptyListItem="true" 
                        EmptyListItemText="Make a choice" 
                        EmptyListItemValue="NR"
                        OnDataBinding="rcbRelease_OnDataBinding"
                        ></telerik:RadComboBox>
                </telerik:EditItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ComponentJob" UniqueName="ComponentJob" HeaderText="ComponentJob"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Operation" UniqueName="Operation" HeaderText="Operation"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Quantity" UniqueName="Quantity" HeaderText="Quantity"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Priority" UniqueName="Priority" HeaderText="Priority"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Status" UniqueName="Status" HeaderText="Status"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="LastEdit" UniqueName="LastEdit" HeaderText="LastEdit"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your having trouble with the ComboBox because you have EnableLoadOnDemand=true but you have not subscribed to the ItemsRequested event.  See [Load On Demand Overview](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/combobox/load-on-demand/overview) for details.

Since you mention your new to the controls, you might want to get the ComboBox LoadOnDemand working outside of the grid first.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the telerik namespace/prefix from the EditItemTemplate declaration:

Change this:

```
<telerik:EditItemTemplate>
    <%-- RadComboBox --%>
</telerik:EditItemTemplate>
```

To this:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <%-- RadComboBox --%>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Also, please share with us which documentation were you following so that we can double check and report the documentation error.